# Indexing solr documents in asynchronous mode

Tags: asynchronous, search, indexing, solr, documents

I have two questions :

1) Im using solr 7.4 and i want to know if it is possibile to indexing documents while another full import is running on the same  collection where i want to index the document.

2) is it possible to send multiple documents to solr and make him indexing them in async mode? in other words, i need to  index them one by one or there are some api's or options that can open multi threads (...i guess....) and indexing documents without waiting that the first one is done?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both issues are solved by dropping DIH and writing the code sending documents to Solr yourself. Your language of choice will have a Solr library available that you can use, and you can run multiple indexing threads or processes in parallel. Use `commitWithin` to make changes visible as indexing happens, or finish of with a commit message at the end.